# Use Node Version in key for Cache@2 Azure Devops task

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml

Based on [the documentation for the `Cache@2` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm) we set this `key` for the task:

```
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json | package.json'
# etc.
```

Just before that we've installed Node with:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
      versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```

How can I use the version of Node on the Agent as a part of the `key`? Is there something like `Agent.NodeVersion`, and where could I find the documentation on available variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would've preferred to use a built-in variable, but for now I solved it with:

```
variables:
  NodeVersionSpec: 16.x
```

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
      versionSpec: $(NodeVersionSpec)
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
      key: 'npm | "$(NodeVersionSpec)" | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json | package.json'
      restoreKeys: |
          npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
          npm
      path: $(npm_config_cache)
  displayName: Cache npm
```